# Incorrect JPanel position in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gridbaglayout, scrollpane

im using GridBag to display some JPanels with images inside a JScrollPane.
When there are 3 or more images the GridBagConstraints work ok but when i have 1 or 2, they get aligned to the center of the JScrollPane instead of being in their position in the top (like in a gallery)
Here is my code:

```js
JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();
GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
jPanel1.setLayout(layout);
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

JPanel photo = new JPanel();
Dimension d = new Dimension(100,100);
photo.setPreferredSize(d);
gbc.insets = new Insets(0,3,3,3);

gbc.gridx = i;
gbc.gridy = j;
jPanel1.add(photo, gbc);


jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jPanel1);
```

I have omitted the part where i assign an image to the photo Jpanel.
I want the JPanels to stay static in their places and do not align if there is free space.
If im not being clear i can upload a few snaps.
Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that at least one photo has weight (or better, all of them the same weight != 0), and then use GridBagConstraints.anchor = PAGE_START; or FIRST_LINE_START.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GridBagLayout` layouts its components out around the center of the container, this is it's (and sometimes annoying) default functionality.

You could try adding an empty "filler" component (say a `JLabel`) with the `GridBagConstraints` of `weightx=1` and `weighty=1` at a position right of and below the other components in the container.  This will force them to the top/left corner of the container...

**Updated...**

**Centered/default...**

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class GridBagLayoutTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GridBagLayoutTest();
    }

    public GridBagLayoutTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.setSize(600, 600);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            JLabel picture = new JLabel();
            try {
                picture.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/your/picture"))));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                picture.setText("Bad picture");
            }
            add(picture, gbc);
        }
    }        
}
```

**Aligned...**

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class GridBagLayoutTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GridBagLayoutTest();
    }

    public GridBagLayoutTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.setSize(600, 600);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            JLabel picture = new JLabel();
            try {
                picture.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/your/picture"))));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                picture.setText("Bad picture");
            }
            add(picture, gbc);

            JLabel filler = new JLabel();
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            add(filler, gbc);
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: I couldnt make it work..
The other problem is that im adding the JPanels dynamically.

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference (adding the JPanels dynamically).  You can simply remove the filler, add any new panels and place the filler on at the last position (to the right/bottom) position