# Remove an element correctly in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gridbaglayout

```
jPanel1 = new JPanel();
GridBagLayout  layout = new GridBagLayout();
jPanel1.setLayout(layout);
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();


 filler = new JLabel();
 gbc.gridx = 1;
 gbc.gridy = 1;
 gbc.weightx = 1;
 gbc.weighty = 1;

jPanel1.add(filler, gbc);
```

Im trying to remove by doing jPanel1.remove(filler), and placing a new JLabel in that position after that, but is clearly not working. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Apparently this question is related to your last question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/18458887/131872). It gets annoying spending time trying to answer a question when you don't know the context of the entire question. Good luck with the answer, I don't know what other information you may have forgotten to mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to why you're having problems, I can only imagine.

Don't forget that the `filler` component is suppose to be added to the right/bottom of last component....

For example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class GridBagLayoutTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GridBagLayoutTest();
    }

    public GridBagLayoutTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final TestPane pane = new TestPane();
                JButton btn = new JButton("Add");
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        pane.addNewItem();
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(pane);
                frame.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setSize(300, 300);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int gridX = 0;
        private int gridY = 0;
        private JLabel filler;

        private int columnCount = 4;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            filler = new JLabel();
        }

        public void addNewItem() {

            remove(filler);

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Cell " + gridX + "x" + gridY);
            label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = gridX;
            gbc.gridy = gridY;
            add(label, gbc);
            gridX++;
            if (gridX >= columnCount) {
                gridX = 0;
                gridY++;
            }

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = columnCount;
            gbc.gridy = gridY + 1;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            add(filler, gbc);

            revalidate();
            repaint();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It worked..
Im really dumb! I was adding the labels with the weightx and weighty equal to 1 instead of reseting them to 0.!!
Thank u all so much.

Answer (score 2):

If `filler` is just a JLabel, then you can just do

```
filler.setText("add text here");
```

Or if you are replacing a different component, a better way would be to create a panel that uses a Card Layout. Then you can just swap the two components. See the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information.

The other option might be to do something like:

```
GridBagLayout layout = (GridBagLayout)jPanel1.getLayout();
GridbagConstraint gbc = layout.getConstraint(oldComponent);
jPanel1.remove(oldComponent);
jPanel1.add(newComponent, gbc);
jPanel1.revalidate();
jPanel1.repaint();
```

Comment: I really dont want to swap them. Just remove one and put the other in other position. Its really difficult to change everything.. No way i can do this with GridBag?

Comment: This is exactly what the CardLayout does. It displays a different component in the same position. Did you even read the tutorial?

Comment: @camickr For some more context, check out the OP's [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458887/incorrect-jpanel-position-in-gridbaglayout)

Comment: It worked..
Im really dumb! I was adding the labels with the weightx and weighty equal to 1 instead of reseting them to 0.!!
Thank u all so much.